# Can I manipulate mixed text/binary data in the same file using Java?

Tags: java, file, io, inputstream

As I understand it, there are 2 types of File I/O apis in Java.
The text oriented and the binary oriented.
What I can not understand is what do we use when we want to create a file that is a mixture of both text and binary data.
E.g. a simple case of keeping variable length records in a file where each record (of unicode text) has 2 bytes (`short`) of an integer that specifies the record's size.
Is this possible? Or I can only manipulate files of a single type? Text only or binary only?

Comment: That's not really a Java thing. The categorization between text and binary files is quite omnipresent. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file

Comment: Just to point out, if you want to record a size followed by a sequence of chars I would go with [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html), it is  API binary (outputStream) that fit the problem of record primitive types and text (with the `writeChars`) well.

Answer (score 4):

There's no mix, everything is binary, you just have to know what to do with the bytes. Just read the bytes and decide what to do with them.

And you'll probably need more than the two bytes to contain the size, since you will also have to know what find of information you're going to read. So you need to know the size and the type to be able to read it correctly.

You'll probably end up with something like:

```
0      1        3                  (4 + length)
+------+--------+------------------------+
| Type | Length | Actual message content |
+------+--------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand this.If I create in my application a file of records of variable length and I make the design decision that a 2 bytes integer is enough for the size of each record;more over each record contains text in unicode.How will these information i.e. 2 byte of binary integer for the size + the unicode text be written/read to/from the file?

Comment: You have to write the code to do it yourself, just as you are writing the code to write it, you need to write the code to read it. There's no magical way the code will understand what you want and do it for you. Or you can just use a `DataOutputStream` as the comments above mention.

Answer (score 1):

As characters are 'made of' bytes, you can use the binary API (`OutputStream`) to do both, writing binary and text based data. For example:

```
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    out.write(recordSizeFirstByte);
    out.write(recordSizeSecondByte);
    out.write(stringData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

Explanation: This will write two bytes first and then the character data, encoded using [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

Everything is of course stored as bytes, and of course you can read it with any binary reader, but what's important here is how easy it is to work with your data.

When you perform file I/O as text data, it saves you a lot of headache having to deal with encodings, platform-specific standards like new-lines, and other things that involve interpreting the bytes that you are reading in.

When you are reading in binary mode, you don't really have any of those conveniences handled for you. You can read `0x0A 0x0D` and interpret that as separate bytes, but who would really know what they represent without context (line-feed + carriage return)

When I say a file contains "text data" or it is a "text file" I usually mean you can read it with a particular encoding, and thus a file that "mixes" text and binary becomes a little difficult because if you assume it is text data, your program might crash on bytes that should be treated as binary data (eg: two bytes for an integer, rather than converting it to a character in whatever encoding you're using)

It is perfectly possible to create such a file, but you will have to perform your file I/O in binary mode and be consistent (and hope that any input that comes in can be converted to whichever format you decide to use). Though from the comments it looks like the `DataOutputStream` makes it somewhat easier for you.

Comment: But if I write the string as binary and can not read it back, it is not of much use...

Comment: There is nothing special about a string written using a text writer and a string written using a binary writer. They are the same bytes in the end. The difference is that the actual bytes being written may differ depending on the text writer's settings (eg: writing out "a" with a binary writer may be `0x61`, but the text writer might write it out as `0x61 0x00`). You just need to make sure that you are reading and writing consistently. How you read from your file is completely up to you (but if you mix text and binary, then you must read it all as binary data)

Comment: I hope I didn't confuse you with the point I make about why one might prefer using a text reader/writer. It's just, IMO, a lot easier to use a text reader to work with binary data that strictly represents text, because if a text reader comes across 4 bytes that represents a float, it's not going to read it as a float.

Answer (score 0):

Text is represented with binary data so there is nothing stopping you from mixing them.  For instance you can write Java objects to a file and the Java object contains text.

The kind of difference you are talking about is really the various kinds of wrappers that can be put around input/output streams that will put a structure of text lines or binary objects onto the input or output stream.

So if you use a binary wrapper around an output stream, you can write text as binary data.

The effort comes from having to create your own wrappers on the input and output streams so that the stream of binary bytes or data is properly interpreted as binary and text data.

I suggest that you use a class that allows you to create objects that contain the text data and use an object input and object output wrapper to let the Java run time figure it all out for you.

Take a look at this article on [reading and writing serializable objects](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57).

And this [article about object streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html).

And this [article on serializing object has pictures](http://www.wikihow.com/Serialize-an-Object-in-Java).

Comment: I am not interested in writing text as binary data. But writing a mix of binary data and unicode text to the same file. Checkout my comment to the answer of Mauricio

Comment: @Jim, what you do not seem to understand is that it is all binary data and you impose on the binary data a particular structure.  What you appear to want is to have a variable length text strings written to a file in which the file content is a set of objects that are composed of a length field followed by zero or more UNICODE characters.  This is a problem that has been addressed over and over again and it is not new.

Comment: `This is a problem that has been addressed over and over again and it is not new` I did not say or think it is a new problem. I am asking hot it is solved using Java